# Swift: пауза анимации

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть этот код для запуска анимации:

```
func startRotateView(targetView: UIView, duration: Double = 3.0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            targetView.transform = targetView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        }) { finished in
            self.startRotateView(targetView: targetView, duration: duration)
        }
    }
```

Но как еe проставить на паузу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать этот код.

```
    func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        layer.speed = 0.0
        layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }
    
    func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.timeOffset
        layer.speed = 1.0
        layer.timeOffset = 0.0
        layer.beginTime = 0.0
        let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
        layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }
```

В вашем случае

```
pauseLayer(layer: targetView.layer)
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что если выполнить pauseLayer, а потом resumeLayer, то вью начнет вращаться быстрее